# Accessing the UI thread to change dependancy properties in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, thread-safety, dependency-properties, dispatcher

I'm trying to update a dependancy property in VB.Net 4.0 inside of an Async callback. I feel like I am doing this correctly but I'm still getting the "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." error. Does someone see a better way of using delegates in VB.Net 4.0?

```
Private WithEvents myObj as CallingObject
Private Delegate Sub MyErrorDel(ByVal strError as string)

Public Property ErrorMessage As String
    Get
       Return CStr(GetValue(ErrorMessageProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub MySub()
    myObj.CallFuncAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayError(ByVal strError as String)
    'Set Dependancy Property value Bound to UI Textbox
    ErrorMessage = strError
End Sub

Private Sub myObj_CallFuncCompleted(Byval sender as Object, ByVal e as CallFuncEventArgs)
    'Call delegate and pass in error string as argument
    Dim delError as MyErrorDel
    delError = New MyErrorDel(AddressOf DisplayError)
    delError("An error occured")
    Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(delError, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Whenever ErrorMessage gets set inside of DisplayError an exception gets thrown, even though I am using the dispatcher to call DisplayError.

If anyone see any issues with the way I am trying to access Dependancy Properties from a async callback I would really appreciate the feedback.

Thanks for the help!

Oh and I'm pretty new at blogging about code issues. Any suggestions about how to better formulate this question would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that at the call to `Me...` you are already accessing an object owned by another thread, try to store a reference to the dispatcher beforehand or possibly use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't indicate the offending line, I suspect the problem here is that you're invokng your delegate in the line delError("An error occured") rather than waiting until you get to the dispatcher. Consider changing your CallFuncCompeted implementation to

```
Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(AddressOf DisplayError, "An error occureed")
```